# rails association, single record only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have an association like so
`has_many :comments, :dependent => :delete_all, :order => "created_at ASC", :include => [:user]`

this is returning only the first comment. while it should be returning all...

EDIT from comment :

a = Activity.find(1) a.comments a.comments has only one record entry, while Comment.find_all_by_activity_id(1) has 4

EDIT after trials...

It seems that using :include => [:user, :comments] is limiting the result to one comment for every activity.

any idea why? and more importantly how to fix it? I could remove it from include, but i'd like to avoid n+1 queries...

Comment: What is the code that returns only first comment?

Comment: a = Activity.find(1)
a.comments

a.comments has only one record entry, while Comment.find_all_by_activity_id(1) has 4

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the SQL that's being generated for each call, either in the console output or database log file.

Are the generated statements the same?